# Problem on Freezing mt5 model for fine-tuning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I wanted to fine tune a mt5-base model for my project (machine translation) and when I try to freeze the parameters except the language head, I'll get errors: can any one helps me know why this is the case
(also I read in the Docs that fine tuning transformers often yield better results when updating every parameter and not freezing, but I don't have enough processing power for that, and is it even the case?)

this is how I freeze the parameters:

```
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("t5-small")
tokenizer = T5TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("t5-small")

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
model.lm_head.requires_grad = True


training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="mt5-finetuned",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,  ## lower batch sizes
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,  ## lower batch sizes
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=5e-4,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=3,
    # fp16=True,  ## lower precision
)


trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset,#["train"],
    eval_dataset=dataset,#["validation"],
)

trainer.train()
```

But I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```